# Expected Identifier error while assigning array object

Tags: ios

```
APIElement *ap=[[APIElement alloc]init];
ap=[feeds objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]];
```

Above is my snippet in which I want to get the object in feeds(NSMUTABALEARRAY) into ap which is object of APIElement but it is giving me error like "Expected Identifier".

Comment: are you ding this in cellforiNdexpathrow?

Comment: no in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove box from indexPath.row.

```
ap=[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```